# move_uploaded_file how to build a upload directory

Tags: php

I got a easy question, but didn't found answer on Google. I am building an application that will have to run on various servers and I have no idea if it will be installed in root, subdir, or in any other way. Also I don't have idea if it will be installed on IIS, Apache, or other type od server. I have a realy nasty problem. How to build a upload dir that will be always good. That upload dir will be in an application folder, so I have some point to start, but I can't figure it out how to write proper upload dir.

```
//tried this for first time
$upload_dir = getcwd().'upload/img';
//then tried this
$upload_dir = 'upload/img';
//and tried couple of others, but more lame, so I will not post it...
```

The thing is that warning is raised that says failed to open stream: No such file or directory, and another Unable to move $temp_name to 'upload/img'.

Really don't know where is something wrong. I am sure that this is a lame question, but don't know how to do it good.

Comment: solution that done the trick is to add a missing '/' between getcwd() and internal path. This done the trick. Don't know why I missed id.

Answer (score 1):

Use the magic macro `__FILE__` to get a path to the current file, that is, the absolute path to your script. To get the current folder use `dirname(__FILE__)`.

You should be able to base the rest of your pathing logic on top of that.

Comment: i tried that, but code is in class depper in dir tree, so it get me location of that file, and that is no good for me. my attempt with getcwd().'upload/img' was better...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you, as application designer, have to select an appropriate location for your upload directory (or let the user pick one when installing). This location is typically chosen to be outside your web directory root so that noone can type in a URL and obtain direct access to uploaded files, but there are also other ways in which this can be arranged.

Then you have to make sure this [directory exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) and [is writable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) by the web server; the directory can be created and set up appropriately either by requiring your users to do it as a manual installation step or by including an "installer" script as part of your application.

Finally, when a file is actually uploaded you have to construct a path to the upload directory. There are many ways to do this (it also depends on what location you have selected, if the administrator is allowed to choose their own location, etc) but again typically this is done by reading the value of a variable written into some configuration file, e.g.

```
// config.php
$DIR_UPLOAD = '/var/www/upload/';
```

This value would be placed there either by your installer script or manually by the administrator at installation time.

Comment: Is there some good arguments to hide files from url? Since anyway I need url do them?

Comment: @neosatan: Typically you would have this url be a PHP script that accepts a `$_GET` parameter and passes on the contents of the target file with [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). If you do this, your script can perform access control before granting access to the file. If on the other hand the file is accessible directly, then anyone with the URL can access it and you have no control over that.

Comment: That a nice idea. Typically I implemented some access control, but only to files that are not needed to have a direct URL, such as images that from design are accessible. The idea to do that to every uploaded file is still new to me, but I wonder how it perform? Isn't it wasting CPU cycles for files that have to be accessible? Or I am wrong?

Comment: @neosatan: Either you need access control or you do not. CPU cycles do not come into this consideration.